# Do the side missions stack between playthroughs?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-2

I am after the "Did It All" achievement which states "complete all side missions'. I have completed all the side missions apart from killing Terramorphous. I am level 34 and not strong enough to take on Terramorphous.

I obviously don't want to do all the side missions again, do they stack between playthroughs? So in the vault hunter mode play through all I have to do is kill Terramorphous for the "Did It All" achievement, since I did all the other side missions in my normal play through.

Comment: If they don't then you can still go back to playthough 1 to take on Terramorphous once you're level 50.

Comment: wont i be level 34 on my normal playthrough?

Comment: No, your level and gear stay with the character, not the playthrough. The enemeies (save for Terra) will be level 30 or below though

Comment: No, you'll be the same level and have the same kit in both playthroughs, but in P1 all the enemies cap out at about lvl 30, so you won't get much XP from them. Level up and find decent kit in 'True Vault Hunter' mode, but you can OCD the challenges in P1

Answer (score 1):

Doing all the missions includes Terramorphous once you beat him you will get the achievement you don't have to do both play through one and play through to all side quests to get it. My recommendation join up with some other players and take him on once your a level fifty.

Answer (score 0):

The progress on mission don't stack between playthroughs but they expect you to level up in true vault hunter mood and come back a do that mission.